# Error deploying war to JBoss 7.1.1 / ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jboss

I have put a project on hold (which was working) and I am suddenly unable to deploy one of my war to my JBoss server. I get the following output :

```
[2015-09-01 10:40:33,526] Artifact xxx-server-back:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2015-09-01 10:40:33,527] Artifact xxx-server-front:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2015-09-01 10:40:33,528] Artifact xxx-server-site:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
22:40:33,699 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "xxx-server-back-1.0"
22:40:33,920 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."xxx-server-back-1.0".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."xxx-server-back-1.0".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "xxx-server-back-1.0"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Could not load EJB class xxx.server.services.data.items.ItemManager
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:227)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxx.server.services.data.items.ItemManager from [Module "deployment.xxx-server-back-1.0:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:225)
    ... 7 more

22:40:33,930 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 4) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "xxx-server-back-1.0" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"xxx-server-back-1.0\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"xxx-server-back-1.0\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"xxx-server-back-1.0\""}}
22:40:33,935 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment xxx-server-back-1.0 in 5ms
22:40:33,937 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 4) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."xxx-server-back-1.0".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."xxx-server-back-1.0".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "xxx-server-back-1.0"

[2015-09-01 10:40:33,978] Artifact xxx-server-back:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2015-09-01 10:40:33,979] Artifact xxx-server-back:war exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"xxx-server-back-1.0\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"xxx-server-back-1.0\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"xxx-server-back-1.0\""}}
22:40:34,020 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "xxx-server-front-1.0"
22:40:34,114 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS018559: Deployed "xxx-server-front-1.0"
[2015-09-01 10:40:34,127] Artifact xxx-server-front:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-09-01 10:40:34,127] Artifact xxx-server-front:war exploded: Deploy took 600 milliseconds
22:40:34,175 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "xxx-server-site-1.0"
22:40:34,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "xxx-server-site-1.0"
[2015-09-01 10:40:34,223] Artifact xxx-server-site:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-09-01 10:40:34,224] Artifact xxx-server-site:war exploded: Deploy took 696 milliseconds
```

The ItemManager class which fails to deploy is declared as :

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class ItemManager {
```

The rest of the code is irrevelant as commenting it did not change the error. If I remove the @singleton @startup, the deployment fails on the next bean of my war so it makes me think of a JBoss configuration/dependency problem. Other war/jar files not containing beans are sucessfully deployed.
Anyone having an idea on how to debug this ?

Comment: Do you put the beans inside the war? Why don't you put them all in an ear with the beans separate from the war. We use this configuration successfully.

Comment: Yes the beans are in the war. As said in my post, it worked fine "before", so it does not seem related to packaging (or at least not to war vs ear)